# Problem loading google vision credentials

Tags: python, macos, google-api

I've been trying to run layout parser example from here https://layout-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/parse_ocr/index.html

The problem is that when I try:

```
ocr_agent =lp.GCVAgent.with_credential('/Users/luizapalma/Dropbox/vision_api_credentials.json',
                                       languages = ['en'])
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module layoutparser has no attribute GCVAgent
```

What is striking in this is that I could run this code in my PC, but not in my Mac. Could this be a problem with the way I write my path? Or something security feature of the macOS? I would really appreciate to know if someone has run into similar problems.